# EJB JPA Architecture

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I have an application where I use EJB and JPA. Currently I have the following architecture:

Entity:
`ActionEntity`

Service:
`ActionService`

The Entity is the JPA-Entity and the Service is where all the CRUD operations are implemented in. `ActionService` implements the `GenericService` interface (DAO-operations)

```
public abstract class GenericServiceImpl<T, PK> implements GenericService<T, PK> {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    private Class<T> type;

    public GenericServiceImpl(Class<T> t) {
        this.type = t;
    }

    @Override
    public T create(final T t) {
        this.em.persist(t);
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(final PK id) {
        this.em.remove(this.em.getReference(type, id));
    }

    @Override
    public T find(final PK id) {
        return (T) this.em.find(type, id);
    }

    @Override
    public T update(final T t) {
        return this.em.merge(t);    
    }
}
```

Thus, the `ActionService` is the DAO for the `Action` entity. I wonder if this is a good architecture?

Would it be better to create an DAO for `Action`, e.g. `ActionDao` which implements only the basic DAO operations. The `ActionService` could then implement an own `create` method which has some additional business logic and afterall calls the `ActionDao`? Or would you think this is overkill?

Comment: Asking for opinions is as off-topic as you can make it. My opinion is: this kind of service/DAO design is cargo cult programming. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming .

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a common practice to separate service (business logic) layer from data layer. This approach in fact has multiple benefits:

1. You will be able to group multiple simple DAO calls in one service call, which in turn will help you to handle transactions easily
2. Another idea would be that extraction of DAO layer will make your life easier when you will decide to switch to any other storage (XML or NoSQL) or you decide to switch JPA to plain Hibernate

So basically this is the main idea of SRP from SOLID - separation of responsibilities.